# nginx http redirection to https

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to redirect http to https. below is my nginx config for default.

```
    server {
    listen   80;
    server_name _;
    #rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

and config for default-ssl is as below.

```
    server {
    listen   443;
    server_name _;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    #return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
}

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
```

Problem is my http config works but https config do not work. 
Update-1: Now my both config works however I am still not able to achieve my objective. Below is my objective. 
 1. http://example.com ---> https://www.example.com
 2. http://www.example.com ---> https://www.example.com
 3. https://example.com ---> https://www.example.com

Comment: You'd also need to insert ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate in the server block that does redirection on port 443. Please see the answer provided by @humanjhawkins.

Comment: I was able to make it work somehow. But still I am not able to achieve http to https redirection. my site works well in below 2 condition.
`http://example.com`
`https://example.com`

What I want to achieve is below.
`http://example.com ----> https://www.example.com`
`https://example.com ----> https://www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** In hindsight, I realize I missed part of your question. Leaving this here, as it should help others searching for help with this issue, and because it is a potential solution... Not sure if the Certbot part is compatible with your needs or not. Hope it helps.

Here is a walk-through of how I set up secure http/2 with redirects. (We will make the self-signed certificates below)

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name _;
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The real site

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html { }

    ## SSL Configuration
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA$
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ecdh_curve      secp384r1;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_stapling        on;
    gzip off;

    ## Headers
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
}
```

There are a few more steps before launching... You'll want to generate better Diffie–Hellman key for improved security:

```
sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048
```

Add self-signed certificate for unrecognixed URLs. Nano into the OpenSSL config:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Uncomment the line beginning with  “req_extensions = v3_req”. Then, add the following to the bottom of the [ v3_req ] section:

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1 = ***YourIPAddress***
```

With that configuration done, you can create the self-signed certificate:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 10000 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt -extensions v3_req
```

Then, add an externally validated certificate for domain and subdomain named websites. This prevents your users from getting warned that you may be untrustworthy. It requires a properly registered domain to work, but otherwise automatically adds the configuration for the certificates to your site config.

```
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Finally:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

If you have an index.html page at the configured location, your https including the redirects should work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve http to https redirection issue with following changes in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And below changes in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default-ssl` file.

```
server {
    listen   443;
    server_name _;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```